# Hibernate hbm2java

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm2java

I am generating annotated pojos via hibernate code generation in eclipse. Classes are generated fine, but class for views are composed of @EmbeddedId and i dont want that. I want to have attributes directly in this class. I found an option "Generate basic typed composite ids" in generation dialog, but when i uncheck it, it would generate view classes with  @EmbeddedId too, but will not generate corresponding  Id classes. Is there a way to generate these classes without  @EmbeddedId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used from this: [Hibernate Pojo Generator](http://hibernatepojoge.sourceforge.net/) and the result was exactly what  wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The @EmbeddedId annotation is generated if the associated table doesn't have a primary key. So just set a primary key and re-generate the code.